# How to filter by field and perform full text search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have document like this:

> {   id: 1,   tag: "tagName1",   text: "Hello world" }

I need to perform full text search (field "text") within documents with tag "tagName1". I can only make match query or filter by tag.

How can I do that together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).  It is the basic constructor to combine multiple queries together:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": { "text": "Hello world!"}
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "tag": "tagName1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```